# Best way to pythonically get a list from a dict, extend it and put it back

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm relatively new to python and programing and have code that is working, however I'd like to know if there is a better more condensed way to achieve the same thing.

My code creates a dictionary with some context key value pairs, then I go and get groups of questions looping a number of times. I want to gather all the questions into my data dictionary, adding the list of questions the first time, and extending it with subsequent loops.

My working code:

```
   data = {
              'name': product_name,
              'question summary': question_summary,
          }  
   for l in loop:
      <my code gets a list of new questions>
      if 'questions' not in data:
           data ['questions'] = new_questions['questions']
      else:
           all_questions = data.get('questions')
           all_questions.extend(new_questions['questions'])
           data ['questions'] = all_questions
```

I've read about using a default dict to enable automatic creation of a dictionary item if it doesn't exist, however I'm not sure how I would define `data` in the first place as some of its key value pairs aren't lists and I want it to have the extra context key value pairs.

I also feel that the 3 lines of code appending more questions to the list of questions in data (if it exists) should/could be shorter but this doesn't work as `data.get()` isn't callable

```
data['questions'] = data.get('questions').extend(new_questions['questions'])
```

and this doesn't work because extend returns none:

```
data['questions'] = all_questions.extend(new_questions['questions'])
```

Ok so I figured out how to condense the 3 lines, see answer, below however I'd still like to know if the `If: else:` is good form in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the `setdefault` method:

```
data.setdefault('questions', []).extend(new_questions['questions'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so Quack Quack I figured out how to condense the 3 lines - this works:

```
data['questions'].extend(new_questions['questions'])
```